# multibyte symbols not displaying properly in rails3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8

I have just upgraded an app from rails 2.3.14 to 3.2.8
ruby has stayed at 1.8.7

In the 2.3.14 app symbols originating from Ms Word and pasted into the rails app display fine. In the upgraded app they dont.

Examples:

In Rails 3 wouldnâ€™t

In Rails 2 wouldn’t

Note that in both cases the app is displaying content from the same Mysql database.

Comment: Did you switch to the mysql2 gem as part of your upgrade?

Comment: Yes I am now using mysql2 gem

Comment: mysql2 forces the connection to utf8 if you've previously been stuffing utf-8 data into latin1 columns then this new conversion is corrupting the data.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. The data in the database was written using the old mysql gem. Are you saying that this data would not be utf8?

Comment: Assume that the columns were marked as latin1 (the mysql server default) and that your connection was also configured as latin1 (the default with old mysql gem), but that the data you inserted was utf8. Any sequence of bytes is valid latin1, so mysql inserts the bytes faithfully. Now that you use mysql2  the connection is configured as utf8, so when you ask for the data the server thinks it needs to convert the bytes from latin 1 to utf8. They've already utf8 so you get garbage

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain! We just went through the same issue.

@Fredrick Cheung is correct above. The only way to solve it is to update the column format without converting the data. Simply changing the column format in SQL will cause your utf data to be converted again to utf which really screws it up!

The solution we came up with is to change the column format to binary or blob and then change it again to utf8. This prevents the second conversion. Use binary for VARCHARs and blob for TEXTs and everything should be okay.

Good Luck